# mouse sensitivity not working and input lag in games (linux mint cinnamon)

Tags: linux-mint, mouse, cinnamon, input

I'm using a fresh install of Linux Mint Cinnamon on my Acer Aspire E15 Laptop. [E5-575G53T1]
Everything works fine, except for mouse input, which is completely broken in multiple ways.
1. My mouse shows up four times in `xinput list`:

```
:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer DeathAdder Chroma             id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer DeathAdder Chroma             id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam: HD WebCam                      id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer DeathAdder Chroma             id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer DeathAdder Chroma             id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

2. The sensitivity slider in the mouse settings does nothing. Also, i cant change the sensitivity with `xset m [sensitivity] 0`.

3. I am experiencing severe input lag in games, most notably in TF2. I have tried many things recommended in forums, but nothing helped. (running TF2 in a window, direct mouse input, lowering graphics settings, turning Vsync off. I tried to update the nvidia drivers but that often lead to [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-mint-84/black-screen-at-boot-after-installing-nvidia-driver-4175575354/))

I have been trying to fix this for a week now, I really hope someone here knows something that might help. I know some of my questions have been asked before, but i have not even found one thread that has an answer that worked.